# firebase E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an App that recieves Data(Orders) from Firebase database but I  can't get the RecyclerView to display my RecyclerView.Adapter that is populated with data which a I can verify and see the list in my firebase database

> xml
>   `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rec_list"
        android:background="@drawable/back"

        />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> Java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
public static ArrayList<OrderItems> orderlist2 = new ArrayList<>();
public OrderList_Adapter adap;
ArrayList<OrderItems> orderlist = new ArrayList<>();
/*
    initial declarations
*/
private ValueEventListener morderListener;
private DatabaseReference morder;
private DatabaseReference msingleorder;
private RecyclerView View_Recycler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



       /*
         Inflating Recycler View
         */

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkinfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkinfo == null || !networkinfo.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet Connection Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

        View_Recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rec_list);
    View_Recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    /*
         Setting FireBase references and Listeners on DataChange
     */
    morder = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders");
    msingleorder = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders");
    ValueEventListener orderListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            // User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                OrderItems order = dsp.getValue(OrderItems.class);
                if (order.getWhenConfirmed().equals("#1")) {
                    orderlist.add(order);
                }

            }
            if (orderlist.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No New Orders To Display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                func(orderlist);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            //  Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // ...
        }
    };
    morder.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(orderListener);
    morderListener = orderListener;


}

/*
    @Params Arraylist of Class OrderItems
    Sets the Adapter for Recycler View
 */
public void func(ArrayList<OrderItems> orderlist) {

    adap = new OrderList_Adapter(orderlist, this);
    View_Recycler.setAdapter(adap);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public ArrayList<OrderItems> fetchorder(ArrayList<OrderItems> orders) {
    return orders;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.new_orders) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.ongoing_orders) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, OngoingOrders.class);
        startActivity(i);

    } else if (id == R.id.delieverd_orders) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CompletedOrders.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

> Adapter

```
public class OrderList_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderList_Adapter.ListHolder> {


    static public String orderid;
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date todayDate = new Date();
    final String thisDate = currentDate.format(todayDate);
    Context c;
    private DatabaseReference msingleorder;
    private DatabaseReference muser;
    private List<OrderItems> listdata;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ItemClickCallback itemclickcallback;

    public OrderList_Adapter(List<OrderItems> listdata, Context c) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.listdata = listdata;
        Log.d("dekheinadapter", "" + listdata.get(0).getLowers());
        this.c = c;

    }

    public void setItemClickCallback(final ItemClickCallback itemclickcallback) {
        this.itemclickcallback = itemclickcallback;

    }

    @Override
    public ListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_item, parent, false);
        return new ListHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListHolder holder, int position) {

        OrderItems item = listdata.get(position);
        String uid = item.getUserId();
        orderid = item.getOrderID();
        holder.topQty.setText(String.valueOf(item.getShirts()));
        holder.lowerQty.setText(String.valueOf(item.getLowers()));
        holder.bedsheetQty.setText(String.valueOf(item.getBedsheets()));
        holder.otherQty.setText(String.valueOf(item.getOthers()));
        holder.totalQ.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTotalQTY()));
        holder.totalP.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTotalPrice()));
        holder.whenPlaced.setText(item.getWhenPlaced());
        holder.pickupdate.setText(item.getPickupDate());
        holder.pickuptime.setText(item.getPickupTime());
        holder.username.setText(item.getUsername());
        holder.room.setText(item.getRoom());
        holder.hostel.setText(item.getHostel());
        holder.typeoforder.setText(item.getTypeOfOrders());
        holder.orderid.setText(item.getOrderID());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listdata.size();
    }

    public interface ItemClickCallback {
        void onItemClick(int p);
    }


    /*
     * Holder Class to hold itemview of Recycler View
    */
    class ListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView topQty;
        private TextView lowerQty;
        private TextView bedsheetQty;
        private TextView otherQty;
        private TextView totalQ;
        private TextView totalP;
        private TextView whenPlaced;
        private TextView pickupdate;
        private TextView pickuptime;
        private TextView username;
        private TextView room;
        private TextView hostel;
        private TextView typeoforder;
        private TextView orderid;
        private Button confirmOrderBtn;
        private View container;

        public ListHolder(View iView) {
            super(iView);
            topQty = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.topQty);
            lowerQty = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.lowerQty);
            bedsheetQty= (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.bedsheetQty);
            otherQty = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.otherQty);
            totalQ = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.totalQ);
            totalP = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.totalP);
            whenPlaced = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.whenPlaced);
            pickupdate = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.pickupdate);
            pickuptime = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.pickuptime);
            username = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            room = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.room);
            hostel = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.hostel);
            typeoforder = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.typeoforder);
            orderid = (TextView) iView.findViewById(R.id.orderid);
            confirmOrderBtn = (Button) iView.findViewById(R.id.confirmOrder);
            confirmOrderBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            container = iView.findViewById(R.id.container_item);
            container.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (view.getId() == confirmOrderBtn.getId()) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                String sorderid = listdata.get(pos).getOrderID();
                msingleorder = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders");
                msingleorder.child(sorderid).child("WhenConfirmed").setValue(thisDate);
                Toast.makeText(c, "Order Confirmed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(c, MainActivity.class);
                c.startActivity(i);


            }


        }
    }


}
```

> OrderItems xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container_item"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        >



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/rl">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User:"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>





        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Room:"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/username"
            android:id="@+id/roomt"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/room"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/roomt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/username"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hostel:"
           android:layout_below="@+id/roomt"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/hostelt"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/hostelt"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/hostel"
            android:layout_below="@+id/roomt"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Shirts/Tops :"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hostelt"
            android:id="@+id/shirt"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shirt"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/topQty"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hostelt"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Jeans/Lower :"
           android:id="@+id/lower"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shirt"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lower"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/lowerQty"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shirt"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bedsheet/Curtain :"
           android:layout_below="@+id/lower"
            android:id="@+id/bedsheet"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bedsheet"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/bedsheetQty"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lower"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Towel/Others :"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bedsheet"
            android:id="@+id/towel"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/towel"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/otherQty"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bedsheet"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Total Qty :"
           android:layout_below="@+id/towel"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/total1"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/total1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/totalQ"
            android:layout_below="@+id/towel"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Total Price :"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/total2"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/total2"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/totalP"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total1"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type Of Order:"
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/place"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/type"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/typeoforder"
            android:layout_below="@+id/place"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="When Placed:"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/place"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total2"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/place"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/whenPlaced"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total2"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pick Up Date:"
            android:layout_below="@id/type"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:id="@+id/pick"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/type"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/pickupdate"
            android:layout_below="@id/type"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pick Up Time:"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pick"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/pickt"

            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"


            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pickt"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/pickuptime"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pick"

            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OrderID:"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pickt"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/order"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"


            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/order"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/orderid"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pickt"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            />



    <Button
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/confirmOrder"
        android:layout_below="@+id/order"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#64B5f6"
        />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: forgot to add firebase gets data from another app therefore both apps are in the same firebase project.

Comment: can you share order_item.xml

Comment: @NavneetKrishna yes.

Comment: @NavneetKrishna I've just edited with the order_item.xml

Comment: @NavneetKrishna It also says that both private ValueEventListener morderListener; and private DatabaseReference msingleorder; is assigned but never accessed

Answer (score 0):

you are only setting the adapter if you have data. so if you don't get any data you actually haven't set any adapter for your recyclerView. set your adapter in both conditions.

Comment: As you can see I have set an Adapter for recyclerView

Comment: @CrazCray but you have done that in your func method and called it only where you have data... . when you don't have any data you are showing only a Toast.

Comment: I have made changes but error remains. It also says that both private ValueEventListener morderListener; and private DatabaseReference msingleorder; is assigned but never accessed

Comment: @CrazCray I need to see your new code to see what the problem is. But I know that the " is assigned but never accessed " warning shows up whenever you have a variable and assigned values to it but you have never used it for getting data.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I found out the Error was that I had the wrong rules in my firebase database